deploy to existing Azure Kubernetes Cluster from github actions
I am trying to deploy to an existing Azure AKS cluster with Github actions.
My plan is to build an a docker image, push it to Azure Container Storage and then use that image to deploy to AKS.
The problem is that "kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml" does not find the deployment.yaml file. How can I point it to it or is there a better option?
echo $(ls -a) does not return any files. The local path is /home/runner/work/App/App
This is the acr.yml file
name: Build and Deploy to AKS

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    # Step 1: Checkout the code
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    
    # Step 2: Log in to Azure Container Registry (ACR)
    - uses: azure/docker-login@v2
      with:
        login-server: ${{ secrets.ACR_LOGIN_SERVER }}  # ACR login server
        username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}  # ACR username
        password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}  # ACR password

    # Step 3: Build and push Docker image to ACR
    - run: |
        docker build . -t ${{ secrets.ACR_LOGIN_SERVER }}/app:${{ github.sha }}
        docker build . -t ${{ secrets.ACR_LOGIN_SERVER }}/app:latest
  
  deploy-to-aks:
    needs: build-and-push
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    # Step 4: Log in to Azure
    - uses: azure/login@v2
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

    # Step 5: Set up kubectl with AKS credentials
    - name: Set up kubectl
      run: |
        az aks get-credentials --resource-group ${{ secrets.AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP }} --name ${{ secrets.AKS_CLUSTER_NAME }}
    
    # Step 5.5: Check if files are present
    - run: |
        echo "Current directory: $(pwd)"
        echo $(ls -a)
    
    # Step 6: Deploy to AKS (Apply deployment and service files)
    - name: Deploy to AKS
      run: |
        kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
        kubectl apply -f service.yaml



The problem was that I did not use
- uses: actions/checkout@v4

again after I started the next step.
Then kubectl is aware of all files.
